# iOS terminated app wakeup with iBeacon packet in sleep mode

Tags: ios, ibeacon, wakeup

Can iOS receive iBeacon packet in sleep state.
I killed app and restarted then kept phone it in sleep mode.
My terminated app not waking with iBeacon packet.

Comment: Was your phone outside the beacon region when you killed the app?  How long did you wait after turning on the beacon? It can take some minutes to detect a region when the app is terminated

Comment: The device was was in beacon reason when device reboot and I kept the  device screen off after reboot. When screen on iPhone can detect iBeacon packet with in 5 minutes but in app killed reboot and screen off iOS not receiving iBeacon packet. I waited for around 30 minutes still no wake up. So can any one suggest what might be the reason for this kind of behavior.

Comment: My phone in beacon region when i killed app. I waited for around 30 minutes. I checked by putting console log . didEnterRegion procedure is not geting called.

Comment: Can Anyone let me know how I can handle this.

Comment: @Paulw11 The device was was in beacon reason when device reboot and I kept the device screen off after reboot. When screen on iPhone can detect iBeacon packet with in 5 minutes but in app killed reboot and screen off iOS not receiving iBeacon packet. I waited for around 60 inutes still no wake up.